# Process image in frontend or backend when creating an image from user input?

Tags: javascript, java, html, spring

I am writing a web-app using Java Spring, where I get user input and then write the inputted text into a already made image. Should I write on image using HTML5/JS or in the back-end using Java? I need to save the image on DB and also show it to the user.
How can I do it so I don't put too much load on the Server

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"too much"*? It depends. If you do it client-side you must also consider the security implications of the client providing an incorrect result.

Comment: The user data is going to be extracted from FB, which means no wrong input from the user's side.